# Pass an Array of audio files to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I store those audio files from "raw" folder stored in:

```
int[] lessonClips = { R.raw.button_a, R.raw.button_2, R.raw.button_3,
                R.raw.button_4, R.raw.button_5, R.raw.button_6 };
```

into an ArrayList with HashMap parameter something like 
**ArrayList < HashMap < ?>>**

The class I'm using has the following method

/**
Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
and store the details in ArrayList
* */

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
                    File home = new File(new String("/sdcard/audio"));

                    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
                        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                            // Adding each song to SongList
                            songsList.add(song);
                        }
                    }
                    // return songs list array
                    return songsList;
                }
```

So I'm trying to convert those audio files to strings to use them inside that method

Comment: What are you trying to do? Couldn't you just have an ArrayList of clips or a HashMap, rather than both?

Comment: What would HashMap's key and value be? HashMap is already an array that stores key-value pairs.

Comment: What is the value of R.raw.button_*. I know they're represented as integers in the array but what are they in XML?

Comment: If I understand your question, they are ".mp3" files,

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Jrom and 10s. Why use HashMap. 
Use ArrayList.

Comment: You mean something like: ArrayList<Integer> LessonClips =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you are trying to do. I would have an alternative solution for you. Despite using the `HashMap` like this try implementing this for your code to be much more concrete to future changes.

Implement song object with properties:

```
public class Song {
   String title;
   String path;
   int resource; //R.raw.*
   //setters and getters
}
```

And you then have this object: `ArrayList<HashMap<int, Song>>;`

In that way you have all the song details in one object, you are making different playlists the way you want and in HashMap you have a ID for each song so you can access them easily.

If you don't care about giving each song an ID you could do: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Song>>`.

In the future you might need to add an artist or something in the song. This is much more robust to such changes and the best way to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm thinking. From your code, it looks like you're only pulling mp3 files from a specific directory. Which means you'll only have one playlist. If this is the case, I would just store the names of the songs like so:

```
ArrayList<String> songList;
```

Or like:

```
ArrayList<Song> songList; //10s' suggestion.
```

As for your original question, you could try something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < lessonClips.length; x++)
{
    songList.add(getApplicationContext().getResources().
               getResourceEntryName(lessonClips[x]);
}
```